# Unexpected read_csv result with \W+ separator

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input file I am trying to read into a pandas dataframe.
The file is space delimited, including white space before the first value.
I have tried both read_csv and read_table with a "\W+" regex as the separator.

`data = pd.io.parsers.read_csv('file.txt',names=header,sep="\W+")`

They read in the correct number of columns, but the values themselves are totally bogus. Has any one else experienced this, or am I using it incorrectly

I have also tried to read file line by line, create a series from `row.split()` and append the series to a dataframe, but it appears to crash due to memory.

Are there any other options for creating a data frame from a file?

I am using Pandas v0.11.0, Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `'\W'` means "not a word character" (a "word character" being letters, digits, and underscores), see the [re docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), hence the strange results. I think you meant to use whitespace `'\s+'`.

Note: [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) offers a `delim_whitespace` argument (which you can set to True), but personally I prefer to use `'\s+'`.

Comment: My mistake with the \W. Both \s+ and delim_whitespace work. Documentation seems to suggest delim_whitespace offers better performance. 

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your data looks like, so I can't reproduce your error. I created some sample data and it worked fine, but sometimes using regex in read_csv can be troublesome. If you want to specify the separator, use " " as a separator instead. But I'd advise first trying Andy Hayden's suggestion. It's "delim_whitespace=True". It works well.

You can see it in the documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html